# Drawing an iscosceles triangle of asteriks on C++

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and I'm trying draw an iscosceles triangle using asteriks. My code looks like:

```
int main(){
for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The top half therefore comes out but how can I start decrementing immediately after reaching j==10 so that i get the bottom half. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to @space_voyager this code support dynamic size so you can have as large as you can define with the size.

The algorithm here is

1. Check if current index or iteration is in the middle (in this case, 11. Programmatically is 10).
2. If true, iterate j from 0 to current index of I.
3. If false (that means that the current index is greater than the middle), iterate j from size - I in decreasing order.

## How size - I works?

At the first iteration where it is true (I > 10, therefore when I = 11) size - I = 21-11. You get 10, hence the output will print 10 times. Second time I = 12. You'll get decreasing result as you go.

```
int main(){
    int size = 21;

    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(i <=size/2)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (i > size/2)
        {
            for(int j=size-i; j>0;j--)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

> ```
> *
> **
> ***
> ****
> *****
> ******
> *******
> ********
> *********
> **********
> **********
> *********
> ********
> *******
> ******
> *****
> ****
> ***
> **
> *
> ```

## Edit

As per space_voyager said, having copy pasted code is not the best practice. Here's the updated code (similar to his, I only added the dynamic part. Change the value of size, you change everything)

```
int main(){
    int size = 20;

    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
        int k;

        if(i <=size/2)
        {
            k = i;
        }
        else if (i > size/2)
        {
            k = size-i;
        }

        for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, but it's generally not good to have copy-pasted parts of code like you do with the for loops that print the asterisks.

Comment: Yeah, realized that. Had the answer in my mind when I saw this question. Took some time to load the compiler and you answered. Still your code is much more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int i=1;i<20;i++){
        int k;
        if (i<=10)
        {
            k = i;
        }
        else
        {
            k = 20-i;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

The basic idea is to switch the mapping from the maximum number of asterisks being `i` in the first half of the triangle (up to line 10) to the mapping `20-i` for the second half of the triangle.

Comment: @Twista Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer in case it meets your needs :)

Comment: Needs a bit of  explanation, but that's easily solved with descriptive variable names.